# What version of ltpa version does Liberty support?

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty, ltpa

In Websphere Liberty, what version of ltpa does it support? Is there a way which I change to version 1 vs 2?

Thanks.

Joshua

Answer (score 0):

It should be LTPA token 2. the token name is ltpatoken2 and I would not expect they downgraded the security.

If you check the default name of the token 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSCKBL_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/twlp_sec_sso.html

Comment: Thanks. as the cookie name it ltpatoken2 I think they used ltpatoken2. In addition as LTPA token2 implementation is a more secure version I would not expect Websphere would downgrade security